# .com domain registered offshore

Tags: domains, domain-registration, legal, privacy

I want to register a .com domain, without risking it being seized by America.

Articles such as these worry me:

> http://www.wired.com/2012/03/feds-seize-foreign-sites/
>
> http://www.pcworld.com/article/2847672/no-you-cant-seize-country-tlds-us-court-rules.html

I do not want another domain as sadly customers like ".com" too much.

If I use an offshore Japanese registrar like Anonymous Speech, would it make it any more resistant to takedown?

> https://www.anonymousspeech.com/anonymous_domain.aspx

This question is just related to ".com", not other country domains, and I especially will not get a ".us" domain or something silly!

Comment: The Internet is a lousy place to get legal advice, and my opinion isn't any better.  But from the article, it seems pretty clear that the US courts have jurisdiction over the .com domain.  Even if they didn't, they could put a lot of pressure on so-called "foreign registrars."

Comment: The U.S. Government does not go around seizing .com sites without cause. Are you planning on doing something that will violate law or otherwise be something that will harm or mislead others?? Under normal circumstances, you do not have to worry. Just do not be a jerk.

Answer (score 8):

According to [Judge William A. Fletcher's opinion on Office Depot v. Zuccarini](http://www.ca9.uscourts.gov/datastore/opinions/2010/02/26/07-16788.pdf), the jurisdiction over a domain name is dependant on the jurisdiction of the domain name **registry**. The [registry for .com domains is VeriSign](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/.com), which is [headquartered in Virginia, USA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verisign). Assuming that the judge's opinion is still applicable, this means the jurisdiction of .com domain registration now falls under Virginia law (note that the headquarter of VeriSign had moved, at the time of the case, VeriSign's headquarter was in California).

Note that domain name registry is **not** the same as domain name registrar. A registrar registers your domain name on the registry, who maintains the primary database for domain registration. According to the the opinion above, it doesn't matter where the registrar is located, as the jurisdiction of the registry is what matters for determining who had jurisdiction over a domain name registration.

In conclusion, no you cannot buy a .com domain from non-US registrar if you don't want to deal with US laws.

I am not a lawyer.